# Python Как убить поток threading по id или имени?

Tags: python, многопоточность, threading

```py
import threading
import time

class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.array = []
    def timer(self):
        for i in range(100):
            self.array.append(f"id {threading.get_ident()} - {i}")
            time.sleep(5)
    def main(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            response = str(input(">>> ")).lower()
            if response == "start":
                thr = threading.Thread(target=self.timer)
                thr.start()
            elif response == "get":
                print(self.array)
            elif response == "threads":
                for thread in threading.enumerate(): 
                    print(thread.name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_thread = threading.Thread(target=test().main)
    my_thread.start()
```

Вывод из консоли:

```plaintext
>>> start
>>> start
>>> threads
MainThread
Thread-1
Thread-2
Thread-3
>>>
```

Знаю, что в multiprocessing можно убить поток, но долго будет переписывать проект.

Answer (score 0):

***Вы можете убить поток при помощи метода stop_threads,***
например:

```
stop_threads = False
testTr = threading.Thread(target = run, args =(lambda : stop_threads, ))
testTr.start()
time.sleep(1)
stop_threads = True
testTr.join()
```

**Таким образом при помощи bool переменной stop_threads, и метода join, можно легко килльнуть тред**